# tapestry-hibernate and 2 databases

Tags: hibernate, tapestry

I have a Tapestry5.1 app using [tapestry-hibernate](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/tapestry-hibernate-core/conf.html) which now needs to connect to a 2nd (separate, not redundant or load balanced) database.

I've read that you can do this in hibernate by creating 2 separate session factories.

I'm not sure how to configure this in tapestry-hibernate though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not supported, and I don't think it will be in the near future. See [this feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-48).

Instead, you could wire up JPA or Hibernate through Spring and just inject your repositories into your components; that works no matter the amount of databases.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this thread
http://tapestry.1045711.n5.nabble.com/Using-multiple-databases-td2468101.html#a2468101